# Facebook meta tags in Joomla: Use 'read more' images and text

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, user-interface, joomla, content-management-system

Im trying to add facebook 'like' buttons to my joomla site. At the moment im adding meta tags to my articles using a plugin. The problem with this is that it is VERY manual. What I want to do is use the information in the 'read more' field of my article to populate the facebook 'like' comment and image.  I use the 'read me' intro text throughout my site so would make it very easy to integrate my old articles with the 'like' button and will also mean that for any new articles, I still only have to write the main article and the 'read more' info.

Havent managed to find any plugins that offer this feature. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would personally suggest using the [K2 extension](http://getk2.org/) for your articles. It includes a Facebook like, Tweet and Google + button for each article. It also won't be a lot of hassle to set up and you can import all you default Joomla articles to the component therefore you won't have to create each one again.

Comment: im using a yootheme template. Integration with K2 is poor so this isn't an option.

Comment: my company uses the Yootheme Streamline template and we have K2 installed. works like a charm. which template are you using?

Comment: Im using Downtown - I'd read in a few places that there were a few CSS issues when installing K2 and using a yootheme template.

Comment: hmm very odd. well I would recommend contacting Yootheme about the issue and using K2, or finding another plugin

Comment: installed K2. My templates are all a bit screwy using K2. However, I do like the how facebook 'like' works. Exactly like i want - using the 'read more' info. K2 is a bit too screwy to use on my site. Do you know anything else I can use?

Comment: I have never really used facebook like buttons apart from the one on the K2 component so I can't recommend anything at the moment. Best thing to do would be to look on the JED site and see which extensions are popular